# How can I handle custom NULL string with Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data file look like below:

```
// data.txt
1    2016-01-01
2    \N
3    2016-03-01
```

I used `\N` to represent a null value for some reason. (It's not a special character, it's a string consists of 2 chars: `\` and `N`).

I want to create DataFrame like below:

```
case class Data(
    val id   : Int, 
    val date : java.time.LocalDate)

val df = sc.textFile("data.txt")
           .map(_.split("\t"))
           .map(p => Data(
               p(0).toInt, 
               _helper(p(1))
           ))
           .toDF()
```

My question is how can I write the helper method ?

```
def _helper(s : String) = s match {
    case "\\N" => null,                // type error             
    case _     => LocalDate.parse(s, dateFormat) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where an Option type will come in handy.

I changed the custom null value to make the case more explicit but it should work in your case. My data is in a .txt file like so:

```
Ryan,11
Bob,22
Kevin,23
Asop,-nnn-
```

Notice the `-nnn-` is my custom null. I use a slightly different case class:

```
case class DataSet(name: String, age: Option[Int])
```

And write a pattern matching function to capture the nuances of the situation:

```
      def customNull (col: String): Option[Int] = col match {
           case "-nnn-" => None
           case _ => Some(Integer.parseInt(col))
      }
```

From here it should work as expected when you combine the two:

```
  val df = sc.textFile("./data.txt")
.map(_.split(","))
.map(p=>DataSet(p(0), customNull(p(1))))
.toDF()
```

When I do a `df.show()` I get the following:

```
+-----+----+
| name| age|
+-----+----+
| Ryan|  11|
|  Bob|  22|
|Kevin|  23|
| Asop|null|
+-----+----+
```

Treating the ages like a string gets around the problem. It might not be the fastest to parse values like this. Ideally, you could also use an `Either` but that can also get complex.